# Linux commands - abort operation with timeout

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

I'm writing a script and at some point I call to "command1" which
does not stop until it CTRL+C is invoked.

1. Is there a way to state a timeout for a command? Like:
   command1 arguments -timeout 10
2. How do I write a CTRL+C command in textual form?

Thx!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by sending a Ctrl+C in textual form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `timeout` command from GNU coreutils (you may need to install it first, but it comes in most, if not all, Linux distributions):

```
timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
```

For instance:

```
timeout 5 ./test.sh
```

will terminate the script after 5 seconds of execution. If you want to send a KILL signal (instead of TERM), use `-k`flag.

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) you have the full description of the `timeout` command.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

```
jekyll -server & sleep 10;pkill jekyll
```

Could do for your situation.

Comment: Warning: you will kill any and all processes called "jekyll" with this. Much better to save the PID of the one you are interested in (it's in `$!` after the command is launched) and kill just that one.

Answer (score -1):

in your script you can set a wait. `wait 10` would wait 10 seconds and as for exiting the program without `CTRL + C` look into the `exit` command. If you use `exit 0` it means ok. There are different versions, but I don't know what they mean exactly off the top of my head.

```
exit 1
exit 2..... so on and so forth
```

Update

---

@ Celada

No need to bash. You could have just said "maybe you didn't understand the question correctly" Stackoverflow is here to help people learn, not tear them down. They invented Reddit for that. As for the exit codes, you can force the program to exit by issuing the exit() command with a code. Directly from [linux.die.net](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/exitcodes.html).

```
Exit Code Number Meaning Example Comments 
1 Catchall for general errors let "var1 = 1/0" Miscellaneous errors, such as "divide by zero" 
2 Misuse of shell builtins (according to Bash documentation)   Seldom seen, usually defaults to exit code 1 
126 Command invoked cannot execute   Permission problem or command is not an executable 
127 "command not found"   Possible problem with $PATH or a typo 
128 Invalid argument to exit exit 3.14159 exit takes only integer args in the range 0 - 255 (see footnote) 
128+n Fatal error signal "n" kill -9 $PPID of script $? returns 137 (128 + 9) 
130 Script terminated by Control-C   Control-C is fatal error signal 2, (130 = 128 + 2, see above) 
255* Exit status out of range exit -1 exit takes only integer args in the range 0 - 255
```

Comment: This makes no sense. That's not at all what the `wait` command does, and I have no idea how you mean `exit` to be used.